# I have a question in prefix sum algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, prefix

```py
import time,random

n=int(input("put your number:"))

X=[random.randint(-999,999) for i in range(n)]

print(X)
#pr1 start
before1 = time.clock()
def prefixSum1(X, n):   # code for prefixSum1
    for i = 0 to n-1 do
        S[i] = 0
        for j = 0 to i do
            S[i]=S[i]+X[j]      
    return (S)
after1 = time.clock()
#pr2 start
before2 = time.clock()
def prefixSum2(X, n):   # code for prefixSum2
    S[0]= X[0]
    for i = 1 to n-1 do
        S[i]=S[i-1]+X[i]
    return (S)
after2 = time.clock()
#
random.seed()   
print(after1 - before1)
print(after2 - before2)
```

This is my code and what I am trying to make is that I randomly generate the array X from -999 to 999 and check the time of two algorithms. But whenever I run the code, it shows >

```py
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'py3_run' failed
    make: *** [py3_run] Error 1
      File "Main.out", line 11
        for i = 0 to n-1 do
              ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea what is wrong with my code. I tried to find on the internet but it seems they are the same as me...

Comment: `for i = 1 to n-1 do` is not valid python syntax. You probably want `for i in range(1, n-1):`

Comment: All of your loops are incorrect syntax. I'd suggest reading the [python docs on flow control](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not use valid python syntax for your `for` loops; the documentation on [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) statements clearly describes the syntax. In short, you need to change

```
for i = 0 to n-1 do
```

to

```
for i in range(n - 1):
```

and

```
for i = 1 to n-1 do
```

to

```
for i in range(1, n - 1):
```

You can check the documentation for [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to learn about how it works.

Comment: if it's ok to ask one more question, the results of time keep coming up like 2.999999999999531e-06
1.9999999999985307e-06 are these correct? it is my first time to you the time function, so i am confused now...

Comment: The times you're seeing are extremely small because "nothing" is happening between your `time.clock()` calls - you define the function but they are not executed. Between your timing calls, you need to call the function using `prefixSum(X, n)`.

Comment: you mean i need to write code like this?? before1 = time.clock()
prefixSum1(X, n)
after1 = time.clock()

Comment: Yes, that's right. Of course, you should look into the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html) module as a better way of timing function calls.

Comment: before1 = time.clock()
prefixSum1(X, n)
after1 = time.clock()
print(after1 - before1)

before2=time.clock()
prefixSum2(X,n)
after2=time.clock()
print(after2 - before2) i put these codes below the return(S) however, the error NameError: name 'S' is not defined has came out. i wonder why this error did not happen before, and suddenly came out after i called the funtion

Comment: The body of your function `prefixSum2` was not evaluated before it was executed, therefore this type of undefined variable error would not be thrown.

Comment: @DeadlyCuteprogramming If my answer has solved your problem, would you kindly [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it?

Comment: Of course, ur answer has solved my problem. Just one more question, I am really sorry, but I couldn't understand "not evaluated", can you tell me more specifically, please? You mean my function was not activated?

Comment: What I mean by that is that python doesn't check for problems like undefined variables when you define the function; this type of error will only appear when the function has actually be called in your code. One reason for this is that you could define S after your function has been defined, in which case there would be no need for the error.

Comment: Is it right I have to define S when I call the function to solve this error?

Comment: `S` of course needs to be defined somewhere, most likely inside your function.

Comment: I tried to define "S" but still confused... I still didn't get where and how to define it. If I put S=[] above the function, it says list assignment index out of range. And I change the randomly generated list to S from X, it says X is undefined. Can you advise me, please?

Comment: If you are adding elements to a list `S`, you should use `S.append(X[0])`, rather than `S[0] = X[0]`. This is more than we should address in the comments section, I recommend you go and read up on lists: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and sorry for keep asking.